# Mouse pointer position on event not centered on arrow tip on THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to determine the position of click events on the screen when using THREE.js with an Orthographic camera.

However, the position (as determined in a similar way as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553209/orthographic-camera-and-selecting-objects-with-raycast)) is not accurate. It is on the mouse pointer area but not exactly on the tip.

By looking at online examples, I can see that for perspective cameras this works correctly.

Is this behaviour correct or is there a problem with my code? Is there a way to align the determined position with the arrow tip?

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    var ray = projector.pickingRay(vector, camera);
    pointer.position = vector.clone();
    pointer.position.z = 0;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pozzoe/y6yS4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a little CSS:

```
body { margin: 0 }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6yS4/4/

Also see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277).

three.js r.65