# What is Three.js raycaster exactly doing?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have seen example codes for collision detection using Three.js which all have a piece of code as:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
```

my question is, what is event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1 &  event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 exactly? why these values?

I need to write a code for orthographic camera hit detection, but I first need to realize what is happening in perspective camera case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1
```

maps a pixel coordinate from Screen Space to a point in Normalized Device Coordinate ( NDC ) Space.

```
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
```

maps a point from NDC Space to a point in World space.

`Raycaster` then creates a ray from the camera position through that world point.

If you need help understanding these concepts, see the references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/should-i-start-learning-webgl-or-use-three-js/11970687#11970687).

Also, for an orthographic camera, you need to use a slightly different approach. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553209/orthographic-camera-and-selecting-objects-with-raycast/18553739#18553739) for more info.

three.js r.66