# How to select objects when using the Orthographic camera in Three Js

Tags: javascript, three.js, ray-picking

I've got an isometric level going and I'm trying to select objects within the level.

I've looked at a few Stackoverflow answers including this one [Orthographic camera and selecting objects with raycast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553209/orthographic-camera-and-selecting-objects-with-raycast) but at the moment, nothing seems to be working. Something is off, perhaps it has something to do with my camera set up, so here is the relevant code I am using.

```
// set up camera
scope.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - scope.cameraDistance * aspect, scope.cameraDistance * aspect, scope.cameraDistance, - scope.cameraDistance, - height, 1000 );
scope.camera.position.set(0 , 0 , 0);
scope.camera.rotation.order = scope.rotationOrder; // = "YXZ"
scope.camera.rotation.y = - Math.PI / 4;
scope.camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(- 1 / Math.sqrt(2));
```

When I loop through my matrix and add the tiles, I add them all to a `new THREE.Object3D()` and then add that object to the scene. My `onMouseMove` event looks like this

```
onMouseMove:function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var scope = Game.GSThree,
        $container = $(scope.container.element),
        width = $container.width(),
        height = $container.height(),
        vector,
        ray,
        intersects;

    scope.mouse.x = (event.clientX / width) * 2 - 1;
    scope.mouse.y = - (event.clientY / height) * 2 + 1;

    vector = new THREE.Vector3(scope.mouse.x , scope.mouse.y , 0.5);
    ray = scope.projector.pickingRay(vector , scope.camera);
    intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scope.tiles.children);

    if(intersects.length) {
        console.log(intersects[0]);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that something is very off. The ray intersects with things when it is no where near them and also seems to intersect with multiple children of `tiles` at a time. If I log `intersects.length` it sometimes returns 3, 2 or 1 object(s). Just in case it is relevant; my material for each object mesh is a `new new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial()` with an array containing 6 `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` passed in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the stupidest thing; my container element had `padding-left:250px;` on it. Removed that and it works. Always correct for your offsets!