# How to use ros3djs? Having problem to get the coordinates of the map

Tags: angular, ros, ros2

I am currently using ROS2djs and ROS3djs for my angular website. I want to be able to add waypoints on the robot map. The imagined flow will be clicking on the map to get the xyz coordinate and then sending the details to the topic and a new waypoint will be created and displayed on the map. Please send help I just started on this and am unsure of where to get hold of the proper documentation of ROS too...I am also using noetic and foxy for ROS.

I tried to use https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/issues/376
but i have error using event3D.domEvent.

tried this as well [Get mouse clicked point's 3D coordinate in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698393/get-mouse-clicked-points-3d-coordinate-in-three-js)