# Issue is offset between mouse pointer and point markers in orthographic mode

Tags: javascript, three.js

My point is not moving under the mouse pointer in orthographic mode.
In perspective camera it is working perfectly while not in the orthographic mode
Below is the image that what is happening.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfcGT.png)

I have tried the things in this link [Orthographic camera and selecting objects with raycast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553209/orthographic-camera-and-selecting-objects-with-raycast)

The code I am trying.

```
//          var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
   //       mouse.x = ( event.clientX / 
                viewer.renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            // mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / 
    viewer.renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( scope.mouse.x, scope.mouse.y, 0.5);
            //console.log("mouse values  ",scope.mouse.x, scope.mouse.y);
            //console.log(scope.scene.cameraP)
            let camera = scope.scene.getActiveCamera()
            vector.unproject(camera);
            console.log(vector)
            var direction = vector.sub(camera.position).normalize();
            var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, direction);

            var pointClouds = [];
            scope.scene.referenceFrame.traverse(function(object){
              if(object instanceof Potree.PointCloudOctree || object instanceof Potree.PointCloudArena4D){
                pointClouds.push(object);
              }
            });

            var closestPoint = null;
            var closestPointDistance = null;

            for(var i = 0; i < pointClouds.length; i++){
                var pointcloud = pointClouds[i];
                var point = pointcloud.pick(scope.renderer, scope.scene.cameraP, ray);

                if(!point){
                    continue;
                }
                var distance = viewer.scene.getActiveCamere().position.distanceTo(point.position);
                console.log(distance)
                if(!closestPoint || distance < closestPointDistance){
                    closestPoint = point;
                    closestPointDistance = distance;
                }
            }

            return closestPoint ? closestPoint : null;
        };
```

Here getActivecamera() is a function which switches between Perspective camera and Orthographic camera.

Below is the image what I want.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GU0p.png)
Please Help I am stuck for the last 3 week in this.

Comment: Please demonstrate the issue with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/. This will make it much easier to debug your code and find a solution.

Comment: Dear brother it is very long code I can not put it here just imagine 50000 line of code in jsfiddle :)

Comment: The idea is to isolate the issue into a smaller test case.

Comment: No I can not do that because many things depends on many things so I can not break it in small part.